# Will using the TABLOCK and HOLDLOCK hints in SQL Server 2005 COMPLETELY prevent inserts until the end of the transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

I need to retrieve the identity field generated by SQL Server 2005. Usually I would just use SCOPE_IDENTITY or add an OUTPUT CLAUSE to the insert, however neither of these method help in this situation: as there is an INSTEAD OF trigger attached to the table. Next I considered @@IDENTITY, but as there is also another trigger attached to the table, this is no good either. So I figured I'd have to use IDENT_CURRENT. However as this is not session safe I need some way to ensure no other session can insert into the table until I have retrieved the new ID. I've experimented with using the TABLOCK and HOLDLOCK hints, this seems to work, but I'm not a DBA. So my question is, will using the TABLOCK and HOLDLOCK hints in SQL Server 2005 COMPLETELY prevent inserts until the end of the transaction?

Hopefully this contrived example will explain the situation. (I realise that, functionally,  a stored procedure could replace both the triggers in this case.)

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
 PersonID  INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
 FirstName VARCHAR(50)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE PersonHistory
(
 PersonHistoryID INT IDENTITY(5,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 PersonId INT,
 FirstName VARCHAR(50)
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER PersonAudit ON Person
AFTER Insert
AS
INSERT INTO PersonHistory (PersonID, FirstName)
SELECT Inserted.PersonID, Inserted.FirstName
FROM Inserted;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER PersonCleaner ON Person
INSTEAD OF Insert
AS
INSERT INTO Person (FirstName)
SELECT UPPER(Inserted.FirstName)
FROM Inserted;
GO

BEGIN TRAN;

INSERT INTO Person WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK) (FirstName) 
VALUES ('George');

--SELECT @@IDENTITY AS '@@IDENTITY'; -- 5 
--SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Person') AS 'IDENT_CURRENT'; -- 1
--SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS 'SCOPE_IDENITIY'; -- NULL

DECLARE @PersonID int;
SELECT @PersonID = IDENT_CURRENT('Person');
SELECT @PersonID; -- 1

COMMIT TRAN;

--SELECT * FROM Person;
--SELECT * FROM PersonHistory;

DROP TABLE Person;
DROP TABLE PersonHistory;
```

Comment: All this complication, instead of indexes and complete access serialization just to replace `FirstName` with `upper(FirstName)`?? Just put a constraint and then fix the client side code that breaks the constraint...

Comment: I agree with Remus. Why dont you use a stored procedure for your insert, and then before the insert you parse the FirstName to uppercase, or do it form the application?

Even so, you might get away ignoring the uppercase, but just make sure when you select or compare you do it in uppercase? Or just change your collation to CI if the whole purpose is for case sensitivity.

Comment: I realise that I could use a stored procedure in this case, that is why I worte " (I realise that, functionally, a stored procedure could replace both the triggers in this case.)". This is just a simplified  example of the situation which demonstrates the problem. Yes, ideally a new sp would be created and the client code changed, but that is not an option right now.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be the TABLOCKX hint which specifies that an exclusive lock is taken on the table until the transaction completes. Exclusive (X) locks prevent access to a resource by concurrent transactions. No other transactions can read or modify data locked with an exclusive (X) lock.

Comment: @usr - so are you saying the answer to this question (Will using the TABLOCK and HOLDLOCK hints in SQL Server 2005 COMPLETELY prevent inserts until the end of the transaction?) is "Yes"?

Comment: @Colin I think so. I'm not exactly advocating this solution but it would work.