# SQL Table not locked even using tablock & holdlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using SQL Lock on a table. here is my query:

```
set transaction isolation level serializable 
go
begin transaction 

select * from emp
waitfor delay '00:00:40'
rollback transaction
```

Now, when I try to access table 'emp' from somewhere else (by opening another query analyzer and firing select query on emp table), still I get data. It should not return data, as table is locked for 40 seconds.

NOTE: I'd also tried  "***with (tablock,holdlock)***" , still not working.

How can I make table inaccessible for that 40 seconds???

Comment: You should check this Link may Be Solve your Proble http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454242/will-using-the-tablock-and-holdlock-hints-in-sql-server-2005-completely-prevent

Comment: @J.D.: the question you linked to does not appear to have a conclusive answer...

Comment: *with (tablock,holdlock)* is **SQL Server** syntax. Yet you have tagged the question with MySQL. What are you really using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had got my answer

```
set transaction isolation level serializable 

go

begin transaction 

select * from emp with (TABLOCKX,holdlock)

waitfor delay '00:00:40'

rollback transaction
```

It locks table, no one else can access it thenafter for 40 seconds.

Comment: And yet, you still haven't told us the ACTUAL problem you are trying to solve......I shudder to think how many 'bad' solutions there are out there....

Comment: Mitch, sorry for not explaining my problem IN DETAIL! Case is, supoose I hv SQL-QueryAnalyser1 and I am upating on 'table1'. Now, I open SQL-QueryAnalyser2, and fire select query on same table (that table is still been updated by SQL-QueryAnalyser1). Practically, select query in SQL-QueryAnalyser2 SHOULD NOT return me data, since it is updated by another query.
HERE WHERE PROBLEM STARTED, that SQL-QueryAnalyser2 was returning me data, which now using holdlock, do not give me data (IT SHOWS QUERY IS PROCESSING IN SQL-QueryAnalyser2, TILL UPDATION IN SQL-QueryAnalyser1 IS COMPLETED).
Clear????